# How to mock Styled JSX 'global' property in Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, next.js, styled-jsx

When trying to run tests on a NextJS project i'm coming up against the following error:

```
TypeError: _css.default.global is not a function
```

I've added a `__mocks__/styled-jsx/css.js` file that contains the following code in order to mock StyledJSX:

```
const css = () => {
  return "";
};

export default css;
```

This takes care of the files that contain normal css decalrations from styled-jsx, but not for my App.js file which contains

```
// CSS reset
const styles = css.global`
  html,
  body,
  div,
  span,
  object,
  iframe,
  ...
```

and

```
<style jsx global>{`
          @import "${mockHeadImport}";
          ${mockBodyImport === mockHeadImport
            ? ""
            : `@import "${mockBodyImport}";`}

          body {
          ...
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use jest coverage in Next.js styled-jsx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59942808/how-can-i-use-jest-coverage-in-next-js-styled-jsx)

Comment: @juliomalves - unfortunately not. This takes care of mocking instances of ```css``` but not ```css.global```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

I've changed my import inside `App.tsx` from `import css from "styled-jsx/css";` to `import { global } from "styled-jsx/css";`, and my css declaration from `css.global` to `global`, and modifed my mock `css.js` file to:

```
const css = () => {
  return "";
};

const global = () => {
  return "";
};

export { css as default, global };
```